# If you are a Half-Giant Brawler, what size are your fists for damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a friend setting up this character, and we were not sure, since Half-Giants can use weapons upto one size larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## RAW is Unclear

Powerful Build never mentions unarmed strikes explicitly, only mentions “wielding weapons” – and technically, unarmed strikes *are* (kind of) a weapon, and “wield” is mostly just the verb for “what you do with a weapon.” But you do generally need to *have* a larger-sized weapon in order to *wield* it, and nothing says that the half-giant *has* a larger unarmed strike, even if they could wield it without penalty if they did.

## From the description, though, it seems like they ought to

Half-giants are described as being, well, very large. Their hands are large enough to *wield* Large weapons; that appears to indicate that they’re also large enough to *deal damage* as Large weapons in and of themselves. Yes, half-giants are not truly Large category – they do not take up a 10' square, nor do they have a 10' reach – but they certainly seem large enough for the small increase in damage that you get from being a size category larger for unarmed strikes.

## And for balance, it should *definitely* be Large

There is nothing special about unarmed strikes that justifies making them the sole exception to the half-giant’s racial ability to benefit from larger weapons. They are actually generally weaker weapons than real weapons. So a half-giant brawler should use the Large Brawler column in Table: Small or Large Brawler Unarmed Damage to determine his or her damage. Even doing so, the brawler is a very weak class; even with this minor benefit, the character may struggle mightily.

Comment: We know it wont be the strongest character, but we are playing with a bunch of beginners so the GM is doing an easy campaign.  Allowing us to make some fun characters we normally wouldn't.